# Lock keyboard and mouse while running xdtool commands through a sh script

Tags: shell, sh, xdotool

Consider the following  illustrative sh script which uses `xdtool` to open a new tab in the terminal, change it to tab 1, and then write "Hello world":

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ${0%/*} || exit 1 # run from this directory

xdotool key ctrl+shift+t                                   #Open new terminal tab

xdotool key alt+1                                          #Switch to the tab 1 of the terminal

xdotool type "echo \"Hello world\""                        #Write something

xdotool key Return                                         #Press "Enter"
```

If I write something or click the mouse button somewhere else while the script is running, the text "Hello world" may be written where I clicked, mingled with the letters that I typed in the keyboard. I would like to lock the keyboard and mouse while the `xdotool` commands are executed so that this can't happen. Perhaps there's a `xdotool` option for that purpose, although I didn't find any. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first type xinput in terminal to list the devices. Then Select the ID of the device that you want to disable. Add lines to your script as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

export DISPLAY=:0
xinput set-int-prop $ID "Device Enabled" 8 0

cd ${0%/*} || exit 1 # run from this directory

xdotool key ctrl+shift+t                                   #Open new terminal tab

xdotool key alt+1                                          #Switch to the tab 1 of    the terminal

xdotool type "echo \"Hello world\""                        #Write something

 xinput set-int-prop $ID "Device Enabled" 8 1

xdotool key Return
```

Comment: This seems to be the path for a solution. There's however a problem with respect to the permissions to access the devices. The following error occurred to me:

"X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  20"

Comment: Also, I want to point out a lapse: the command "xinput set-int-prop $ID "Device Enabled" 8 1" should be after the command "xdotool key Return".

Comment: After looking into this site https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput, I think now that the devices stated by the "xinput list" command which are not stated by the "libinput list-devices" command will not be  supported. Therefore, the "xinput set-int-prop" command will only work for devices that are stated by both "xinput list" and "libinput list-devices" commands.

Comment: Put "xinput set-int-prop $ID "Device Enabled" 8 1" after "xdotool key Return" in your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Yes, sorry I have tried it and it worked. Maybe there is a better way less technical, especially in the device ID.

Comment: Your answer had anyway served my needs, since it allowed to lock the most important mouse and keyboard devices that I use.

Comment: The other problem may be a question for another post.

Comment: Im glad to hear it helped !